# Powershell function with $args and named parameter

Tags: powershell

I currently have the following powershell function:

```
function d { doppler run -- $args }
```

However, I would like to run something like `d -Config dev ...` and have that translate to

```
doppler run --config dev -- ...
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an **optional parameter** to your function you would no longer be able to use [`$args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#args) the same way you're currently using it. By adding a new parameter to your non-advanced function the same would be always bound positionally (`-Config` would be always bound hence wouldn't be optional).

What you could do instead to replace its functionality is turn your function into an [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2) one and have a parameter that takes [`ValueFromRemainingArguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefromremainingarguments-argument).

I haven't tested it but I believe this should do the trick.

```bash
function d {
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [string[]] $Arguments,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Config
    )

    end {
        doppler @(
            'run'
            if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Config')) {
                '--config', $Config
            }
            '--'
            $Arguments
        )
    }
}
```

Then both options should be available, with and without `-Config`:

```bash
PS ..\> d some arguments here
PS ..\> d -Config dev some arguments here
```